# Arduino Control by PC

Tags: c#, c++, arduino-uno

I am trying to make a automatization by controlling a 12V motor using an Arduino Uno.

I have this code on the Arduino:

```
const int transistorPin = 9;  

 void setup() {

   pinMode(transistorPin, OUTPUT);
 }

 void loop() {

   int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);

   int outputValue = map(sensorValue, 0, 1023, 0, 255);

   analogWrite(transistorPin, outputValue);
 }
```

pretty simple, so with this I can control the Engine speed using a protoboard, a potentiometer, and a additional 12V input directly to the protoboard.

so this physical thing works, but now the issue here is that I cannot create a method in order to control the arduino with the PC.

The idea is that a C# system (already exist, I cant modify it) to run an application, .exe, .bat or anything, and this application must control or tell the Arduino to start working, I dont know, by controlling the Voltage, by changing the USB on and off with a delay, to send a Byte and if the arduino receive it it start with the program, I am open to suggestions and help.

the idea is that this Motor pulls one label and only one, then stops, until this application on the PC runs again and activate the arduino to deliver another label and stops again.

Comment: From c# you can communicate with the arduino over Serial(SerialPort) interface.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `Serial.read` on `loop` to read a `byte`, or another type, then, according with the value received, change the `outputValue`.

See this link for more: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read

Comment: in the arduino I am using the int incomingByte along with a if invomingByte > 0 then do the program, but I Can do it on the Visual Basic, on the PC, on putty I do the connection on serial COM8 and every time I press a key, the program starts, so it works, but i cant Automatize this thing, at this moment is only manual.

Comment: sorry, but I didn't understand your question clearly. but I believe this link can help you better: http://www.martyncurrey.com/arduino-and-visual-basic-part-3-controlling-an-arduino/ (it's in Visual Basic - i really don't understand if you wanna control arduino on c# - because of tags - or in VB - because your comment)! Check the full tutorial too to understand better how to comunicate with arduino and pc: http://www.martyncurrey.com/arduino-and-visual-basic-part-1-receiving-data-from-the-arduino/

Comment: Ok thanks for that tutorial, what I want to do is to send a byte to the arduino, for example, to test the connection I use Putty, on Serial COM 8, each enter I tap on Putty sends a byte to Arduino and run the program, but instead of using Putty, must be an app made on VB or CMD or something that only doubleclick into it and run, no interfaces, no buttons, just like a .bat.